# BigCommerce Create Shipment - no response

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I am coding a API to create shipments on Big Commerce.
I am getting responses from the 'Get' URL's - I just can't seem to get the API to respond on the 'PUT'

I fired up a 'Web Responder' and it returns the following:
The tokens etc are moved for security.

Header:

```
{
  "VERSION": "HTTP/1.1",
  "CONNECTION": "close",
  "ACCEPT-ENCODING": "gzip",
  "CONTENT-TYPE": "application/json",
  "AUTHORIZATION": "Bearer ---------------------",
  "X-AUTH-CLIENT": "======================",
  "X-AUTH-TOKEN": "=========================",
  "ACCEPT": "application/json;",
  "ACCEPT-CHARSET": "UTF-8;",
  "USER-AGENT": "West Wind Internet Protocols 5.56",
  "CACHE-CONTROL": "no-cache",
  "COOKIE": "__cfduid=dfebfa0729eeaf50601b1fe187807c6fc1529278210; owner_token=cdc79c402c05c15d01ce0996dcc40654e3a0fe75a256eae3",
  "CONTENT-LENGTH": "171"
}
```

The 'PUT' has:

```
PUT /b7ezoY2bqq2DKg0soyMy
{
  "tracking_number": "PBT0000124",
  "comments": "Shipped by PBT",
  "order_address_id": 392,
  "shipping_provider": "",
  "items": [
    {
      "order_product_id": 1540,
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

As far as I can tell, all the details are correct. I just get no response. Please not this is a 'Desktop' application - not a Website.

Any clues?

Comment: Hi it should be a /POST. Can you try that instead? `OAuth >POST /stores/{store_hash}/v2/orders/{order_id}/shipments`

Comment: @Dave2e Did you reject my edit, only to make almost the same edit yourself? It looks that way to me (rejected by Community user). Apologies if you did not. However if you did, I would appreciate an explanation. Also, your edit missed an improvement to the post that mine had.

Comment: @O.O.Balance, I didn't reject it. If the edits were submitted at the same time, maybe it was superseded by mine.  If there are additional improvements, please make the additional edits.

Comment: @Dave2e Thanks for clarifying. I just had just checked on meta and it suggested you had used "reject and edit". The only thing you missed is a minor typo: "Please not" should be "Please not***e***" at the end of the post. I will not make another suggested edit just for that :-)

Comment: Been working on this. Use Postman for testing. Seems to be something with the keys. Both 'PUT' and POST' return the same results.

Comment: I was getting '403 - Forbidden'. Then got a new set of keys from my customer. After changing to the new keys, the exact same call returned '401 - unauthorised'. The legacy call - with valid token, returns '404'.

Comment: You should be using OAuth for the API Keys. Legacy is not supported on V3 or webhooks. https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Store-API-Accounts/?q=api+key&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1. Can you explain what yo mean by legacy call as well?

Comment: Got it working. Turned out I had the keys in the wrong place. Though - not having a single 'Ship This Order and all products' endpoint is rather annoying.